# An iphone uipickerview that rotates horizontally?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface, uipickerview

I've only seen it in a VERY few iPhone apps... but it looks like a picker that rotates left/right (instead of top/bottom).

They usually put it on 1 line of a tableView... to allow the user to quickly pick between a small number of choices (like 3-10).

How is that coded?

Comment: Here's what the picker should look like:
http://images.macworld.com/images/reviews/graphics/143531-dr_dof_original.jpg

Answer (score 6):

Continuing the answer by Dave DeLong I got it working like this......

In `viewDidLoad` i did this...

```
 CGRect frame = horizontalPickerView.frame;
        frame.size.width = 50;
        frame.size.height = 216;
        frame.origin.x=90;
        frame.origin.y = 200;
        horizontalPickerView.frame = frame;

        horizontalPickerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14159/2); 






- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
        UILabel *lbl = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 20)] autorelease];
        lbl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-3.14159/2);
        lbl.text = @"hi";
        return lbl;
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: For CGAffineTransform dont forget to add QuartzCore Framework to your project

Comment: can you explain the 3.14159/2 ? (i know its PI, but why is it here and why the /2)?

Comment: i did it so that picker is rotated by 90 degrees hence it will scroll horizontally and 3.14159/2 is the value of 90 degrees in radiance

Answer (score 6):

[Here](http://isujith.wordpress.com/2009/03/17/horizontal-uipickerview/) you will find source code for Picker which is horizontally aligned.

Comment: Can't scroll horizontally. You have to tap on each cell to scroll through.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by taking a regular UIPickerView, adjusting its width (via `setFrame:`), and then applying an NSAffineTransform to rotate it 90º.  You'll then need to rotate each item in the picker 90º the other way.

It's a little tedious to do it properly, but it can be done.

Comment: Won't the letters also turn by 90 degrees? I think it is a custom view on the screenshot.

Comment: @Alex yes, which is why you need to rotate each `viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:` by 90º the other way.

Answer (score 1):

@Madhup's code lead me in the general direction I wanted when I searched for the horizontal `UIPickerView` but I then realized the question asked wasn't really addressed so for anyone who was looking for a more suitable answer to the left-to-right rotation. The code in the answers I'd read were all to enable left-to-right swiping, causing the picker to push the labels/rows with higher values to the left of the view. Any ways here's my contribution:

In the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
    yourPickerView.frame = frame;
    yourPickerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(4.71238898); //Instead of rotating clockwise 90° we're rotating 90° counterclockwise. 4.71238898 being ≈270° in radians.
    [self.view addSubview:self.picker];
    self.yourPickerView.delegate = self;
    self.yourPickerView.dataSource = self;
    self.yourPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    self.yourPickerView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

The `pickerView`'s method:

```
  -(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
      UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)] autorelease];
    yourLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.57079633); //Instead of rotating counterclockwise 90° we're rotating 90° clockwise 1.57079633 being ≈90° in radians.
    yourLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"System-Bold" size:18]; //Your font here.
    yourLabel.text = @"yourLabel's text"; //or like me [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, [yourArray objectAtIndex:row]]
    yourLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return label;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a paged scrollview that has the items you want on one per page, and perhaps overlay an image above it if you want nicer graphics for your control, and only allow for horizontal scrolling (don't make the contentSize of the scrollview taller than the size of the actual view, and disable vertical scroll bouncing on the control).

Answer (score 0):

Try this->
Create Plain UIVew of size of UIPickerview, add picker on it.
set numberOfComponentsInPickerView = 1.
set componant width.
Then add small sub views on it to Hide rest of picker. Only rotating wheel of componant should visible.
Transform plain view to rotate it through 90 degree.

Make sure to apply tranform in:

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view 

{

    UILabel *lbl = nil;
    if(view)
    {
        lbl = (UILabel *) [view viewWithTag:11];
    }
    else
    {
        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];
        lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 0, 30, 30)];
        lbl.tag = 11;
        lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18];
        lbl.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(lbl.transform, M_PI +M_PI/2);
        [view addSubview:lbl];
        [lbl release];
    }


    lbl.text =  [dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:row];


    return view;
}
```

Now you can add palin view as a subview for horizontal picker on any view.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create picker programitcally, so that you can create your own sized picker with `CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)` then, you will have to rotate it, but rotating it will also rotate in the Picker's dataSources methods, you will have to rotate the view inverse of picker's rotation, I am including code hopfully it will help

```
.....
...
...
NSArray *arr =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1 mi", @"2 mi", @"5 mi", @"10 mi", @"15 mi", @"20 mi", @"25 mi", 
                 @"30 mi", @"35 mi", @"40 mi", @"45 mi", @"50 mi", @"75 mi", @"99 mi", nil];

    radiusDefaults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arr] ;

    radiusPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 150)];
    radiusPicker.delegate = self;
    radiusPicker.dataSource = self;
    radiusPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = NO;  

    //Resize the picker, rotate it so that it is horizontal and set its position
    CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-1.57);  
    rotate = CGAffineTransformScale(rotate, .1, .5);
    CGAffineTransform t0 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-61, 0);
    radiusPicker.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(rotate,t0);

//  [theNavigationBar.topItem setTitleView:radiusPicker] ;
    UIView *pickerWrapper = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 215)];
    [self.view addSubview:radiusPicker];
    [radiusPicker selectRow:6 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    [radiusPicker release];

.....
.......
....

    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark UIPickerView 
    - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row 
              forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{


        UIView *viewForRow = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 400)] autorelease];

        UILabel *label;

        UIFont *font = [ UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialRoundedMTBold"  size:22];


        label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 70, 350)] autorelease];

        [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [radiusDefaults objectAtIndex:row]]];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        label.font = font;
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        //    label.opaque = NO;
        [viewForRow addSubview:label];

        CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.57);
        rotate = CGAffineTransformScale(rotate, 1, 6.5);
        [viewForRow setTransform:rotate]; 
        return viewForRow;
    }
```

Answer (score -14):

Have you ever considered taking a table view and rotating it?

Didn't think so. Go try that. :)

Comment: I probably wouldn't want to rotate the entire table-view.
(And have the "rows" going top-to-bottom on the screen.)
  
But... maybe the developers are rotating the picker... and some how resizing it down to fit in 1 row of the table-view.
  
But what would the code look like?

Comment: Why don't you try and write it and find out for yourself? That's the only way you're going to learn anything.

Comment: I would strongly suggest reading through all of Apple's documentation at http://developer.apple.com in the iPhone section on getting started, both with iPhone programming and Objective-C.

Comment: So the answer to my question is "go find out yourself"?
  
Or to read 1000s of pages of docs... *NONE* of which say anything about "horizontal pickers"?
  
Wow.  Thanks.   We really don't need stackoverflow.com at all... everyone should just go solve everything on their own.

Comment: It's only 3 short booklets. It took me about two weeks to read through all of them, really read them, and understand them. Because I read through those things, I knew exactly what I wanted to do when I wanted to make something like a sideways picker. (Sideways UIPicker? Horizontal UIPicker?)

Comment: Also I'm specifically harsh on you in this case because from your evident lack of example failures, I can see you haven't even tried anything, which leads me to believe you're being lazy.

Comment: 3 short booklet?   False.
Took you 2 weeks to read them?
(I just don't have time to read WEEKS worth of info... for 1 question.)  
 
So this forum is just to call people 'lazy' when they ask questions?
Wow.

Moderator:  Please delete Sneakyness's account.  He just posts insulting/useless remarks towards everyone trying to learn something here.

Comment: The point I'm trying to make here is that if you would have spent the time to read these books in the first place (like every beginning iPhone developer should), you wouldn't have even had to come here to ask the question.

Comment: @Sneakyness not everyone has the time to devote to Cocoa that you might. Be considerate of others situations. The whole point of SO.com is that people have questions, and we either 1) know the answer or 2) know how to find it. Telling somebody to RTFM is almost never the best answer. ;)